# Raster symbology tab - compact display option for selected colors

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, user-interface, interface

I've recently switched from the 3.0 early adopter release to 3.8, and I'v noticed that the raster style/symbology tab became a lot less...convenient...to use if you're working with more than 5 values, since the displayed colors now take up 3-4 times the height of the the actual value&display text.

3.0

[image]

3.8

[image]

I might be missing something obvious here, but is there a way to switch this back to a compact display? I'm working larger color ramps and not being able to see all values at a glance kind of impacts my productivity. What version number introduced this change?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Viper_63! Perhaps you should post this as a `feature request` on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

Comment: I'd like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious, because this seems like such a pointless change to make. I haven't yet found an option to toggle between sizes, but I'm simply not sure I didn't somehow mess up the UI without intending to.

Comment: If it can help for comparison, on my QGIS 3.8 (running on Docker), the size of the color square is 32x32 px.